# can't load cert and key from storage: failed to get from node cache: connection refused

Tags: ssl-certificate, kong, acme

I am new to kong.Now I am trying auto create and renew SSL certificate with the help of acme plugin. According to their official documentation I followed all the steps but now it says

```sh
2022/01/07 12:23:44 [warn] 32#0: *2043 [kong] handler.lua:100 [acme] can't load cert and key from storage: failed to get from node cache: connection refused, context: ssl_certificate_by_lua*, client: 13.229.141.97, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
2022/01/07 12:23:44 [info] 32#0: *2042 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:SSL alert number 48) while SSL handshaking, client: 13.229.141.97, server: 0.0.0.0:8443
```

```
  - name: acme
    config:
      account_email: myemail@gmail.com
      domains:
        - "example.mydomain.net"
      tos_accepted: true
      renew_threshold_days: 30
      storage: redis
      storage_config:
        redis:
          auth: "password123"
          host: "127.0.0.1"
          port: 6379
          database: 0
```

I have also created service and route

```
  - name: acme-dummy
    url: http://127.0.0.1:65535
    routes:
      - name: acme-dummy
        protocols:
          - http
        paths:
          - /.well-known/acme-challenge
```

added the line below on docker-compose file

```
KONG_LUA_SSL_TRUSTED_CERTIFICATE=system
```

Comment: Can you connect to redis? `redis-cli ping` can check this for you

Comment: Yes, I can connect to redis

Comment: Finally, It is working. The problem was in Redis. Now Redis is deployed without a password. Thanks